# php soap maxoccurs=unbounded

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have WSDL,

```
<xs:complexType name="merchantDetails"><xs:sequence>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="did" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="flowid" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
```

I am trying to send array as follows (var_dump).

```
object(merchantDetails)#3 
  ["did"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "81985801"
  }
  ["flowid"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "MerchantMOTOMID1"
  }
```

But `__getLastRequest` output does not show any tag for did or `flowID`.

Please help in case of how to send unbound data.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information - the WSDL might help, as well as your submit code, and the exact error you're receiving

Answer (score 1):

Following should do the trick if I read the WSDL-instructions correctly. Posting the desired SOAP-request would be very helpful...

```
$param = array(
  'did'=>'81985801',
  'flowid'=>'MerchantMOTOMID1'
)


$soap_instance->merchantDetails($param);
```

or

```
$param = new stdObject();
$param->did = '81985801';
$param->flowid = 'MerchantMOTOMID1';

$soap_instance->merchantDetails($param);
```

either one of them haven't been tested...

Answer (score 0):

set the maxOccurs as bounded

TO be exact, please post your complete source code

Answer (score 0):

```
//You should try to send like this

$arOperationFilter = array(
    'did' => array('81985801','81985802','...')
);


$client = new SoapClient($your_url, $arSoapOptions);

$result = $client->yourSoapOperation($arOperationFilter);
```

Comment: Hi Sergei. Thanks for your contribution but please, explain what's the issue and why your code solves it. Code-olny answers are not encouraged.

Comment: A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.